# Why do I get IllegalFormatConversionException when formatting a hexadecimal string to three digits?

Tags: java, string, format, hex

I am working on a class project where I have to build a two pass assembler for an instruction set we were looking at in class.

In the first pass function, a segment of my code looks like this:

```
        //If the fourth character is a comma, then it follows that the line contains a label.
        if (line.indexOf(',') == 3) {              
            //Store symbol in address-symbol table together with value of location counter
            String symbolTableLine = line.substring(0,3) + " " + String.format("%03X", Integer.toHexString(locCounter)) + "\r\n";                
            symbolTable[symbolTablePos] = symbolTableLine;
            writerSymbTable.write(symbolTableLine);
            //Increment the location counter and the current position in symbol table
            locCounter++;
            symbolTablePos++;
```

My issue is with the following function call:

```
String.format("%03X", Integer.toHexString(locCounter))
```

The goal for this is to convert the location counter to a hexadecimal string (such as "AA", "0", or "F") and add zeros as placeholders until the hexadecimal string is three digits long ("0AA", "000", "00F")

The problem is that I am receiving this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String
```

I know this means that it is not taking in a hexadecimal string for some reason. But I can't seem to figure out why that wouldn't be a hexadecimal string, I mean I'm using Integer.toHexString()...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. If this is not enough code for you to see, then I can post more of the code if you want.

Comment: You realize that Integer.toHexString() returns a String, and you're trying to format it as a number, which is not a number anymore, hence, %x is not valid to use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call `toHexString()` as the `"X"` in `format()` will take care of the conversion:

```
String.format("%03X", locCounter)
```